# Vios x LPAR Clients - SEA relationship

Tags: virtualization, vlan, ethernet, aix

I am developing a script to list all SEA adapters in a VIOs, their related physical, virtual adapters, along with their status and VLAN TAG ids.

I wish to include on this script the VIO clients (LPARs) using the specific SEA  and their VLANs. I know I can do it on the HMC side, but I don't know how to do it on the VIO side.

Can anyone help me with suggestions?

Also I will gladly share the script with whoever is interested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grep hosts in `seastat -d entX` (where `entX` is the SEA device).

You need enable accounting to collect SEA stats

**Check if accounting is enabled on SEA**:

```
lsdev -dev entX –attr accounting
```

**Enable**:

```
chdev -dev entX -attr accounting=enabled
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid this command, because of the script.
But in the it turns out this is the best way, so I had to adapt :)